# Calculated field based on list

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, id

I have a list where the user can add new items. I would like to generate an ID based on who creates the item.

**For example**

- if Person A is the creator, then her ID="10000 + number of items she created". So her first item is 10000, the second is 10001, the third is 10002...
- If person B create an item the ID is 20000 + number of items. I have 5 user in total.

Any method is fine. My plan is to create a list where I store how many items were created by each user and get information from it and update when new item is created. I think I should use workflows, but I don't have experience with them.

Thank you very much for any suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First,** The **ID** and **Created by** are not supported fields in the Calculated Column, For more details check [THE SUPPORTED AND UNSUPPORTED COLUMNS IN SHAREPOINT CALCULATED COLUMN FORMULA](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

**Second,** there is a supported `Count` function that can be used in Calculated Column but based on your scenario it's useless.

**Third,** Based on your description, you said `"My plan is to create a list where I store how many items were created by each user"` so I think you can achieve this by creating a new view in the same list **Grouped By** the `Created By`

[image]

It would give you how many items created by a specific user as shown below

[image]

**Finally,** using SharePoint Designer workflow would be complex and maybe not satisfy your requirements, because you will not be able to control the count of items based on the **current user**!. and I think it's preferred to use `Event receiver` as a coding solution to achieve this scenario!

Comment: Very clear and helpful advice thanks! What I forgot to mentinon is, that the users may delete items too. Is this "Group By method" shows the actual or the total number of item created by a user?

Comment: it shows the actual in the current list! Please don't hesitate to inform me if you need further clarification also Please don't forget to mark the answer if it helped you :) Thanks!

Comment: I upped it thank you! May I ask what method would u prefer if the user can delete items too, so we need the total number if items created by the user to be able to create an uniqe ID?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point, but there is already unique ID for each item you can show it in your view by modifying the view from the above ribbon